# Laurent series of square root of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2 -3z +2} = \sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}, 1<|z|<2$. Does the Laurent series expansion for $f(z)$ exist? Justify your answer.

I'm quite new in Laurent series, so I do not know how to approach this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Laurentcseries exists if you can make the function analytic throughout all of the annulus with no cuts through said annulus.  So ... Can you arrange the cut to avoid the annulus when the branch points are at $1$ and $2$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi To choose branch cuts for  $√(z-1)$ and $√(z-2)$ , I need to choose rays starting from$z=1$ and $z=2$, so can I choose the rays $(-∞,1]$ and $[2,+∞)$ to avoid the annulus?

Comment: The ray from $1$ to $-\infty$ passes through $-1$ and $-2$... .

Comment: If you write $$
f(z) = \sqrt{(z^2-3z+2)} = \sqrt{2(1-z)(1-z/2)}=
\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(1-z)(1-z/2)}
$$ you will see what happens.

Comment: So the Laurent series does not exist because it is impossible to define an analytic branch of f that includes the whole annulus?

Comment: Bull's eye!  Curiuosly, note that $\sqrt{(z^2-3z+2)/z}$ _would_ have a Laurent series because it equals $\sqrt{(1/z)-1}\sqrt{z-2}$ where both branch cuts can now be directed to avoid the annulus.  This is life in the world of complex variables.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely need more practice with this though!

Comment: @OscarLanzi If you, or the MO, elaborated completely the answer, it would be a service to the community. In fact $\sqrt{z^2 -3z +2}$ is Taylor developable at a neighbourhood of zero, so the question is "How to continue it ?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gathering ideas from the discussion, I focus on a **proof** that $\sqrt{z^2-3z+2}$ does admit **no Laurent expansion** within the annulus
$$
\Omega:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\ |\ 1<|z|<2\}
$$
firstly, remark that $\Omega$ being connex, $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ has no zrero divisors and any square root $f$ of $q(z)=z^2-3z+2$ being given, the set of solutions of $f^2=q$ is $\{-f,f\}$. Now,  following an idea of Oscar Lanzi, we define 
$$
g(z)=i\sqrt{1-1/z}\sqrt{2-z}=i\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-1/z}\sqrt{1-z/2}
$$ 
and remark that, in the annulus $\Omega$, we have $|1/z|<1$ and $|z/2|<1$, then $g(z)$ admits a Laurent expansion using the expansion of $(1+Z)^{1/2}$ with, respectively, $Z=1/z$ and $Z=z/2$. Now $g(z)^2=1/z.q(z)$.

If $f(z)$ (any square root of $q$) admitted a Laurent expansion in $\Omega$, it would be the same for $h=f/g$. But, then $h^2(z)=z$ which is impossible as $z$ admits **no** square root within $\Omega$ (to prove this consider that $\rho e^{i\theta}\mapsto \rho e^{i\theta/2}$ is a solution of $u(z)^2=z$ defined on the open domain $\Re(z)>0$ which intersects $\Omega$).